# PHP Check if GET parameter is in .txt file and return a response yes/no

Tags: php, get

I'm new to PHP so I wanted to know how do I make a script which you have to put a GET parameter (index.php?test=value) and it checks is value is in a txt file provided. If the value exists then print yes if no then print no, if there isn't a GET parameter print like ''empty''. Please help me how to do this.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far and we will be happy to point you in the right direction?

Comment: You could use `strpos` and `file_get_contents`.

Comment: I don't know what to try since I'm very new to php..

Comment: I'll post a starting point for you. You should work with some tutorials in the future.

Comment: `<?php
    if( strpos(file_get_contents("./file.txt"),$_GET['id']) !== false) {
        echo "yes";
    }
?>`

Is this right?

Comment: @JasonSmith Does it work? Programming is all about trying :)

Comment: @BenN Yup, it does :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_GET['test'] = 'value';
if(empty($_GET['test'])) {
    echo 'empty';
} else {
    $file ='asdfasdfasvalue';
    if(strpos($file, $_GET['test'])) {
        echo 'yes';
    } else {
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```

You should populate `$file` with the file's contents.

Functions being used...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
http://php.net/strpos
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Thank you! Definitely going to watch some tutorials now.

Comment: By the way, will this work with larger files like 30k lines? :x

Comment: It should. There are other ways to go about this though you could use `fread`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php, and scan the file by chunks. You also may not need the whole file this way because you only care about one occurrence.